# Agregar varios detalles a una venta Django

Tags: mysql, django

Tengo 2 apps **cliente y venta** en donde cliente tiene solo una tabla cliente

```
class Cliente(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Nombres')
```

y **venta** tiene 2 tablas (Venta y detalle de venta) y producto pero eso jala de otra tabla.

```
class Venta(models.Model):
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Cliente')
    fecha =  models.DateField()
    detalle = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name='Detalle del pedido')


class DetalleVenta(models.Model):
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Producto')
    cantidad = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Cantidad')
    venta = models.ForeignKey(Venta,on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Venta')
```

El problema que tengo es de como puedo agregar varios detalles de venta ya que pueden ser **1 o muchos** detalles que se pueden generar al realizar una venta en un mismo formulario.
Ya que si creo un formulario con los 2 modelos solo hay me registrara un detalle y con su venta pero si son mas detalles?

Comment: Te aconsejo que te documentes sobre form_set, se ajusta a lo que necesitas. No te lo pongo como respuesta porque es muy extenso de explicar, pero  espero que por lo menos te haya ayudado a tener un punto de partida, un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias! se le agradece mucho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo que necesitas es usar **formsets** de Django. De esa forma puedes, en una misma factura, incluir varios productos.

Sugiero que le des un vistazo a la documentación oficial de Django acerca de este tema:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/

Es aún un poco más sencillo si decides usar ModelForms y ModelFormsets. En ese caso puedes usar Inline Formsets:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Comment: Muchas gracias ! voy a revisar